# rbind a type of column from a list of tibbles

Tags: r, lapply, rbind

I have four excel files that I have loaded onto R using list.files, and have used lapply to read them in.
My code is:

```
 my_files <- list.files(pattern = '*.xlsx')
 my_list <- lapply(my_files ,read_excel)
```

The files contain many different columns:

```
 lapply(my_list ,colnames)
 > lapply(my_list ,colnames)
 [[1]]
 [1] "JobCard Branch" "Customer Name" "Primary Contact No" "Alt No 1"          
 [5] "Alt No 2" "Reg No"            
 [[2]]
 [1] "CUSTOMER" "Primary Contact No"  "Alt No 1" "REG NO#"            
 [5] "VehModel" "Last Service Outlet"
 [[3]]
 [1] "Company Name" "JobCard Branch" "Service_Branch"          
 [4] "HUB" "Customer Code" "Address"                 
 [7] "Address Line2" "Primary Contact No" "Alt No 1"                
 [10] "Alt No 2" "Alt No 3" "Zip"                     
 [13] "Source" "City" "Vehicle Model"           
 [16] "Make" "Reg No" "Chasis No"               
 [[4]]
 [1] "Last Call Date" "Reg.No" "Model" "Customer Name"  "Contact Number" "Booked Outlet" 
 >
```

Could someone let me know if I can extract only the registration number columns ("Reg No","REG NO#","Reg No","Reg.No") from all these tibbles using rbind or any other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create a vector of column names (`cols`) which we want to extract and then use `lapply` to loop over list of dataframes and subset the columns which match `cols`.

```
cols <- c("Reg No","REG NO#","Reg No","Reg.No")
data.frame(unlist(lapply(my_list, function(x) 
           x[names(x) %in% cols]), use.names = FALSE))
```

A reproducible example

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 2:6)
df2 <- data.frame(a1 = 1:4, new_s = 2:5)
df3 <- data.frame(abc = 1:4)
list_df <- list(df1, df2, df3)


cols <- c("a", "a1", "abc")
data.frame(new = unlist(lapply(list_df, function(x) 
                 x[names(x) %in% cols]),use.names = FALSE))

#     new
# 1     1
# 2     2
# 3     3
# 4     4
# 5     5
# 6     1
# 7     2
# 8     3
# 9     4
#10     1
#11     2
#12     3
#13     4
```

Comment: I am able to get the Reg No columns from each DF/tibble. But I need to combine them into one tibble or even a vector. The output is another list of 4 tibbles.
The output should be from your above example:
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4

Comment: @ShaneBond You could `unlist` and wrap it in `data.frame` or `tibble` according to your preference. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `grep` in case insensitive mode:

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) {
    y <- colnames(x)
    y[grep("\\breg\\b", y, ignore.case=TRUE)]
})
```

This uses the regex pattern `\breg]b` in case insensitive mode, to find the column names which match what you want.